# Is it possible to do cell composition for scATAC-seq data without scRNA-seq data?

Tags: rna-seq, single-cell, atac-seq

**Background** My understanding was that if I did scATAC-seq and I have some clusters of cell groups, the only way I can label it is by correlating those groups with scRNA-seq data.

My lab ordered some scATAC-seq data and the vendor did some complimentary analysis and provided cell composition plots indicating which portion of the cells of type X, Y, Z, so on.

**Question** How is this possible to identity cell composition identifying given cell types? Alternatively is it possible they just used some default RNA-seq data from 10x genomics?

---

Definitions

scATAC-seq stands for "Single-cell sequencing assay for transposase-accessible chromatin"  This attempts to consider genome-wide regulatory landscapes in single cells. scATAC-seq data can be sparse and noisy presenting a challenge for analysis.